# Is Pandante on-topic?

Tags: discussion

**Is it considered on-topic to ask questions about Sirlin Game's [Pandante](http://www.sirlingames.com/pages/pandante) on Poker.SE?**  On one hand, it is very much a "poker-style" game, using a great amount of rules from Texas Hold'em and X-Card Draw, and clearly being inspired by these games in its design.  On the other hand, it uses a custom deck of cards, has many dissimilar rules as well, and its existence is even a sort of snarky stab at being "better" than poker, which could generate offensive community arguments.  At best, it's a valid variation of poker and worth discussion; at worst it's a completely different game that is off-topic.

Comment: Good question & well put. Thanks for asking here first. There is a board/card games site that may be appropriate.

Comment: @TobyBooth Yes, I am aware - I am even a more active member there.  You know, there's always the people who think that this and that site have potential to be merged, too, which is an interesting idea.  I'm sure there's a lot of social politics in that discussion, though.

Comment: True. There was discussion, if I remember right, when the Poker.se site was proposed and it was deemed that poker was more niche and deserved it's own site.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good thing that you asked about this.

I'm going to take the "it's offtopic" side because, from what I can read about it, the differences from poker are quite large. They have very few things in common. Just like the thing that basketball and tennis have in common is that a ball is involved.

I am however open to other opinions, if you think that it should be ontopic.

Comment: I took a quick look at it, watched some of the "see it played" video & it looks vastly removed from what i consider poker. For starters the deck used is proprietary, and not what is used in every other poker game i know. So no,I agree with Radu & say its off-topic.

Comment: @TobyBooth I think I am tempted to disagree myself.  I think the similarities outweigh the differences, and the core is the same.  It tests the same skills, and the same sort of questions of mathematical valuation are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

**I believe that Pandante should be on-topic here at Poker.SE.**

I find that the similarities to the games that inspired it are more common than the differences, and the core of the games are very much intact.  I feel that the games test the same core skills, and that questions about such skills would be very fitting and not at all out-of-place.  For instance, one might ask about the odds of getting a *Rainbow Straight* or a *Floosh* in a given game-state - although these are hand types unique to Pandante, the nature of the questions are not substantially different from questions about Texas Hold'em.

Comment: just a thought. Your example is potentially a drawback as well, as those types of questions will invariably be duplicates of Q's submitted in regard to more common conventional poker game types.

Comment: Also, after investigating a question on open face Chinese, one of the reasons why a game is "poker" is that the hand rankings are of the same structure. Not similar, but the same. Flushes, straights, etc. Not flooshes, et al. Thus requires that the deck is also standardized.